# Flutter: How to get rid of the first touch delay?

Tags: flutter, touch

I have a little issue with Flutter.
I did a clean install and everything works smoothly.
Nonetheless, there is a delay of half a second between my touch and the action of a button (or menu hamburger).
This delay exists only for the first touch action.
After the first touch / click, any further touch action is without delay.

This problem exists on the emulator but also on a real device.

Could you explain to me why (and how to fix it)?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this problem.

Comment: Is this in development (hot reload JIT mode), or release mode (compiled down to ARM code)?  I suspect if you're in JIT mode, the first touch is actually taking a moment to compile that particular code pathway.  That's why the banner says "debug" (it used to say "slow" :).

Comment: @RandalSchwartz It was in development with the hot reload. I compiled a release mode version (with "flutter run -- release") and everything works fine now (no more delay with the first touch) ! Many thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @RandalSchwartz the problem is now solved.

Flutter applications are slower in development mode (with the hot reload).
This cause the app to have a delay with the first touch action (on a button or hamburger menu for example).

This also cause the app to have a long splash screen in development mode (around 3 seconds)

Therefore the solution is pretty simple if you want to get rid of all the waiting times, just launch you app in release mode with the following command:

"flutter run --release"